# MongoDB strongly typed filter and Find()

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and the MongoDB C# driver.

To make the code more readable (and reliable) I decided to give strongly typed objects a try. Therefore I created a POCO...

Only Id and Payload are initially present in the database.

```
internal class MongoDbRepositoryItem
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("rawdata")]
    public byte[] Payload { get; set; }
    public string ProcessingStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProcessingStarted { get; set; }
    public int ProcessingAttempts { get; set; }
}
```

Now there are multiple operations I need to accomplish.
First of all I need to retrieve the oldest unprocessed item.

I was thinking of something like that:

```
var builder = Builders<MongoDbRepositoryItem>.Filter;

// I didn't read about sorting yet. I also need the "oldest" document.
var filter = builder.Exists(item => item.ProcessingStatus, false); 

MongoDbRepositoryItem result = await _collection.FindAsync<MongoDbRepositoryItem>(filter);
```

**But that doesn't compile.** `FindAsync()` expects a BsonDocument. My filter obviously is strongly typed. I couldn't find any answer in the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/).

Answer (score 1):

First thing first :-)

```
var result = await collection.FindAsync<MongoDbRepositoryItem>(filter);
var data = result.ToList();
```

in this line we are expecting a `cursor` and not an single item.
Using `data` we are converitng our cursor to list for later processing;

If we are going to get only first item, then we could use

```
MongoDbRepositoryItem result = collection.Find<MongoDbRepositoryItem>(filter).First();
```

EDIT

```
var b2 = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<MongoDbRepositoryItem>();
var f2 = b2 . Exists(x => x.ProcessingStatus, false);
var result2 = await collection.FindAsync<MongoDbRepositoryItem>(f2);
```

Any comments welcome!

Comment: The error is "Cannot convert from FilterDefinition<MongoDbRepositoryItem> to FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>". Thank you for the First() hint, I will use FindOneAndUpdate() later on.

Comment: mongodriver = latest (2.2.4)

Comment: that's strange  - or there is an issue with full code you have.. please see my edit and test

Comment: that sounds very strange indeed. The answer looks okay here.